# PID for Quadcopters

Tags: arduino, pid

As already mentioned the PID output values that correspond to the error from the desirable error and current error has no units. Let's say we are using only the proportional part of the PID. Is it better to map the output of the PID values to the corresponding thrust values on each motor, or is it better to increase the Proportional coefficient `Kp` until the output values correspond to the proper thrust value to the motors?

For example if my desired angle is 0 and the angle that the sensor is reading is 40 degrees the difference is multiplied by `Kp` and the output is added or subtracted from the current thrust depending on the motor.

If I increase `Kp` too much, then the quadcopter is oscillating and not listening to the controller command that I am sending for the desired degrees from the joystick. If I map the values then it is listening to the joystick commands and not oscillating so much. Why is this happening? Isn't mapping the PID output values to bigger values the same as increasing `Kp`?

Comment: _Let's say we are using only the proportional part of the PID_, is the quadcopter actually using only the proportional part of the PID?

Comment: Yes it does i checked it..

Comment: What do you mean by mapping "the output of the PID values to the corresponding thrust values" ?

Comment: @EugeneSh., I think he means multiplying the output of the controller by some value. @monakons, it may not be bad to tell us "how" you checked it. If you multiply the output of a P controller, or multiply it's `Kp` both by the same value, nothing should change. So either it's not a P controller, or you are not transforming the values in the same way.

Comment: Well, in this case the result should be exactly the same

Comment: What do you mean by "the output is added or subtracted from the current thrust depending on the motor"?  That seems suspect.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have inadvertently created a controller using a Ki only term.
It appears that your Kp term is used by summing it onto the current (last cycles) output. This is effectively creating an integral output.
You need to directly output the Kp term and sum it with a separate Ki term if needed.